# How do I unlock bone charm slots 4-6?

Tags: dishonored

In Dishonored I only have 3/6 bone charm slots available. How do I unlock the last three slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase additional slots from Piero in his workshop over at the Hound Pits between missions.

If you preordered the game, you can also get an additional slot by activating your preorder DLC.

Comment: Too bad steam preorder doesn't get it, does it?

Comment: No, I think Steam is the only retailer without an in-game preorder bonus. (You got TF2 goodies instead.)

Comment: These pre-order DLCs are available in Steam as the 'Void Walker Arsenal' DLC.